# How do I convert std::list<int> to COleSafeArray?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, stdlist, safearray

I have a `std::list<int> listNumbers`. I would like to pass this as a `COleSafeArray` to my C# DLL interface as a function parameter, so that the function in the DLL can work with this array of numbers.

How do I convert `std::list<int>` to `COleSafeArray`?

In the C# file, the function would be:

```
public void Foo(int[] listNumbers);
```

Comment: A `std::list` is a list, not an array. A fundamental difference of both data structures is, that the elements in an array are in a contiguous region of memory. If you need an array you're going to have to create one and copy the elements of the list over. There's no way to prevent the copy.

Comment: @IInspectable I am free to change the source container. It does n't have to be a `std::list`. I can change how I build the array of numbers for passing as a `COleSafeArray` to the DLL. So if `std::list` is a bad choice ...

Comment: Why not just make the "source container" a `COleSafeArray`? Anything else, and you'll have to rebuild the data into a `COleSafeArray`, whatever the container or data type.

Comment: @AdrianMole That is a good idea. Up until now I have tried to keep any "COM" operations confined to the API WRAPPER so that the main application doesn't need to worry about the underlying mechanics. Also, I think my question wording is misleading. Even if I directly create a `COleSafeArray`, how do I do it with my `int` values?

Comment: Using the COleSafeArray as your base type may or may not be a good idea, depending on how much 'work' you'll be doing with the data. But, whatever you choose, you'll be needing calls to the `Create()` and `PutElement()` members of the class to get your data into it. You can't just 'convert' a batch of data into a safe array.

Comment: @AdrianMole I guess my broad term "convert" was meant to embrace any method. I'll sort it. Might even leave it the way I have done it. If I end up sorting it out I'll add an answer.

Comment: `COleSafeArray::AccessData` gives you a raw pointer to the array data. So you can work with it as plain `int*` most of the time - either in case you decide to use it as your "normal" storage, or if you want to copy into it on the COM boundary. E.g. once you have the raw buffer, you can use `std::copy` to copy data from the list into this buffer.